# Installed python library (blink1) can not be imported

Tags: python

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124874/installing-problems-with-python-package-on-mac-os-x-maybe-several-python-versio) I am trying to install the blink1 library on raspbian.

But no matter what I try, I get:

```
>>>import blink1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import blink1
ImportError: No module named blink1
```

I installed it via pip and it is in the correct path as far as I understand it:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
blink1                     python_jenkins-0.4.8.dist-info
blink1-0.0.12.dist-info    pyusb-1.0.0rc1.egg-info
blink1_tests               setuptools
click                      setuptools-18.3.1.dist-info
click-5.1.dist-info        six-1.9.0.dist-info
configobj-5.0.6.dist-info  six.py
configobj.py               six.pyc
configobj.pyc              usb
easy_install.py            validate.py
easy_install.pyc           validate.pyc
jenkins                    _version.py
_markerlib                 _version.pyc
pbr                        webcolors-1.5.dist-info
pbr-1.7.0.dist-info        webcolors.py
pip                        webcolors.pyc
pip-7.1.2.dist-info        wheel
pkg_resources              wheel-0.24.0.dist-info
```

I don't know what else I should try now...

Edit: it does not seem to work with pyhthon3 either:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Mar  1 2013, 11:53:50) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import blink1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>

    import blink1
ImportError: No module named blink1

$ sudo pip-3.2 install blink1
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): blink1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages
```

Edit 2: the last issue might have something to do with the fact that on this installation, the sys.path does only contain the 2.7 libraries, not the v3 dist-packages...

Comment: What version of Python are you using. blink1 will be available only for python version > 3.0.

Comment: I tried with 2.7. Okay then, how do I make the alternative wrapper from https://github.com/todbot/blink1/tree/master/python/alternative_libraries available on my raspberry? I tested it and it works, but I don't want to copy it to every directory that uses blink

Comment: I also do not understand 2 things: why does pip install it if it does not work on py2, and why is the import error so unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file __init__.py is missing from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blink1/

If you run

```
touch /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blink1/__init__.py
```

it should start working.

Reference:
https://github.com/todbot/blink1/pull/224